# Observable.of to watch contents?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Is Observable.of a good way to watch the contents therein? I just want to make an observable that watches a condition, i.e. `let observable$: Observable<boolean> = Observable.of(a === b);` Is that a good method for creating the observable or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give us more details about your explicit example?

If a and b are some sort of streams you could make yourself a "watcher" observable like here

```
let condition: Observable<boolean> = a.combineLatest(b).map(([a, b]) => a === b)
```

**Edit: Input values are plain boolean**

Then you probably have to declare them as BehaviorSubject.

```
a = new BehaviourSubject<boolean>(false);
b = new BehaviourSubject<boolean>(false);
```

To change or get the current value you can use `a.getValue()` and `a.next(true)`

Now you have two streams and can combine them as shown above. If you only need them once in the template, it's also fine to do it like that

```
<p *ngIf="(a | async) === (b | async)">...<>
```

Comment: I have edited my answer - this is the way how to do it in your case

Comment: Nice that's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Observable's creation method doesn't watch changes of value once it's created. You may need use Observable.create directly to call observer's `next` or create subject to push values via `next` when value changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you give a minimum code example for my sample question?

Answer (score 0):

RxJS doesn't do watching of variables as such - it relies on other things generating the events.

I am assuming you are using Angular from the Typescript tag.

It appears that RxJS version 4 did have a $watch method, which would have allowed you to do what you want, but $watch is a dangerous tool as it can end up causing negative performance impacts.

$watch is noticeably missing from Rxjs 5, and there seems to be no indication of how to do this. I think you need to do some further research on this - it might mandate a different approach instead of watching a variable, you might to intercept the event that causes it to change. Think about the redux approach to notification of state changes.